# PSQL Join alternative to return all rows

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, inner-join

I've got a PSQL function that has 3 joins in it and the data is returned in a json object. I have a 4th table that I need to get data from but it has a one-to-many relationship with the table I wish to join on.

This is my current code:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as results from (
                select g.*,row_to_json(o.*) as e_occurence,
                row_to_json(d.*) as e_definition,
                row_to_json(u.*) as e_e_updates,
                cardinality(o.m_ids) as m_count
                from schema.e_group g
                join schema.e_occurrence o on g.id = o.e_group_id
                join schema.e_definition d on g.e_id = d.id
                left join schema.e_e_updates u on d.id = u.e_id
                ) s
```

This gets me an array of objects that follows this rough structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": 11308158,
        "e_id": 16,
        "created_on": "2020-09-09T12:08:07.556062",
        "event_occurence": {
            "id": 9081887,
            "e_id": 16,
            "e_group_id": 11308158
        },
        "e_definition": {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Placeholder name"
        },
        "e_e_updates": {
            "id": 22,
            "user_id": "7281057e-2876-1673-js7d-7cqj611b4557",
            "e_id": 16
        },
        "m_count": 0
    }
]
```

My problem is that the table `e_e_updates` can have multiple records for each corresponding `e_definition.id`.

Clearly the join will not work as hoped in this instance as I'd like `e_e_updates` to be an array of all the linked rows.

Is there an alternative means of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need another level of aggregation. This should do what you want:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as results 
from (
    select 
        g.*,
        row_to_json(o.*) as e_occurence,
        row_to_json(d.*) as e_definition,
        u.u_arr as e_e_updates,
        cardinality(o.m_ids) as m_count
    from schema.e_group g
    join schema.e_occurrence o on g.id = o.e_group_id
    join schema.e_definition d on g.e_id = d.id
    left join (
        select e_id, json_agg(row_to_json(*)) u_arr
        from schema.e_e_updates
        group by on e_id
    ) u on d.id = u.e_id
) s
```

You could also do this with a subquery:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as results 
from (
    select 
        g.*,
        row_to_json(o.*) as e_occurence,
        row_to_json(d.*) as e_definition,
        (
            select json_agg(row_to_json(u.*))
            from schema.e_e_updates u
            where u.e_id = d.id
        ) as e_e_updates,
        cardinality(o.m_ids) as m_count
    from schema.e_group g
    join schema.e_occurrence o on g.id = o.e_group_id
    join schema.e_definition d on g.e_id = d.id
) s
```